# No precompiled R binaries for centOS?

Tags: centos, r

I need to install `R` on my centOS linux server, preferably just by downloading the precompiled binaries on https://cran.r-project.org/, but I don't see an option for `centOS`. Does anyone know where there isn't a centOS option?

Answer (score 0):

Following the Fedora/RedHat download link in the page:

*"EPEL for CentOS and RHEL*

*The Fedora RPMs for R have been ported to CentOS/RHEL by the project Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)."*

So as per the instructions the Fedora/RedHat packages are the ones you want.